# How do I install Linux mint OS on my desktop?

Tags: linux, windows-8, installation

I'm using windows 8 64 bit with 8 GB ram, 500 GB hard disk, and an i5 3rd generation processor. I have recently downloaded Linux Mint and many others OSs like Fedora and Ubuntu as  iso files.

However, after downloading these files I can't see any .exe file to install these OSs.

Comment: Well you need to burn the iso file to a cd or dvd (or create a bootable usb stick) and then boot you system from that disk. Do you want to have dual boot sytem or replacing your windows 8 installation?

Comment: I encourage you to download a free of charge user friendly virtualization suite (VirtualBox or VMware). With any of those you can install a virtual machine and test GNU/Linux. There is also the Wubi thing that allows another possibility of GNU/Linux testing additional to the dual boot, replacement, and virtualization options. I'm betting preparing a dual boot system might be a little dangerous option for you. But you could do it if you do not care of your data or you have a controlled backing up system of any important data you might have stored in your system.

Comment: @uprego wasn't Wubi killed and Ubuntu only by default?

Comment: I don't know, was trying to advice some alternatives. But I suspect the least dangerous approach for this person are virtual machine technologies.

Comment: @user290169 for what are you wanting to install GNU/Linux mint? Isn't it better for you to keep using Microsoft?

Comment: @uprego huh? If the OP wants to install GNU/Linux, they want to install GNU/Linux. Why shouldn't they? I have installed dozens of Linux distros over the years, each time resizing my drives as needed and have never had any data loss. Why would you suggest to anyone that they should not try Linux?

Comment: @terdon because it is plainly clear that if a user is wanting to install an _os_ using a .exe document, allowing him/her to do that is exposing him/her to data loss. It falls well enough below the GNU/Linux entry level.

Comment: @uprego there is no such thing as a magical knowledge threshold beyond which you gain the right to install Linux. Good grief, I knew nothing at all about *nix when I started playing with Linux. I knew nothing at all about Windows when I started playing with that either. That's how you learn, by trying things. If the OP is a newbie, good for them, they can start learning with an open mind.

Answer (score 1):

What you have downloaded is called an [ISO image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image), to use it, you need to save it onto a USB drive or CD and boot from that.

1. Burn the .iso file you downloaded onto a blank DVD disk. Most CD/DVD burners have an option that allows you to burn an image. For example, on nero, just go to File =>Open and then choose the .iso you downloaded.
2. Once the VD has been burned, leave it in your DVD drive and reboot your computer. It should automatically boot from the DVD. Follow the onscreen instructions to install the OS.

If your computer does not boot from the DVD automatically, you will have to [change the boot priority](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm) settings in your BIOS.